# How to make this integrand nonsingular?

Tags: calculus, integration, singularity-theory

$$T = 4\sqrt{\frac{l}{2g}} \int_0^x{\frac{dy}{\sqrt{\cos(y)-\cos(x)}}}$$

So do i just have to find a way so that the denominator does not result in 0? I am to later evaluate it with x = 51. Which leads me to trouble because I get a 0 in the denominator at x = 51.

EDIT:the problem is that I need to figure out how to evaluate this integral and get an answer without actually changing the integrand itself like i did the first time

Second Edit: had to fix question

Third edit: **Potential Solution**

x is a constant therefore, cos(x) is treated as a constant.

$cos(y) - cos(x) = t^2$

$-sin(y)dy = 2t dt$

$dy = -\frac{2t}{sin(y)}dt$

$\int_0^x{-\frac{2t}{sin(y)} * \frac{1}{t}}dt$ 
= $\int_0^x{-\frac{2}{sin(y)}dt}$ = $\frac{-2t}{sin(y)}$ = $\frac{-2\sqrt{(cos(y)-cos(x))}}{sin(y)}$ from y = 0 to x. X is later given as 51 so the solution would be just plug and solve from here?

Comment: Why do you seem to think that $\;\cos y=\cos\left(y-\frac\pi{60}\right)\;$ ?? What is that thing $\;\pi/60\;$ ? Are you mixing something that should be taken with radians with someting ...in *degrees*?

Comment: You could just as well change the whole integral to 0, 1, or any other number; that would be about as appropriate.

Comment: The edit is uninformative. You should rather clarify what you are exactly trying to do and what issue you have with that integral.

Comment: the problem is that I need to figure out how to evaluate this integral and get an answer without actually changing the integrand itself like i did the first time

Comment: It might be helpful to write $\cos(y)-\cos(x)=2\sin\left(\frac{x+y}2\right)\sin\left(\frac{x-y}2\right)$

Comment: Close to $y=x$, the denominator is approximated by the square root of a linear function, so why worry ?

Comment: how would $cos(y)-cos(x) = t^2$ work? and substituting it this way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be written in terms of an elliptic integral of the first type using the identity 
$$ 2\sin^2{\alpha} =1-\cos{(2\alpha)}$$

$$T=4\sqrt{\frac{l}{2g}}\int_{0}^{x}\frac{dy}{\sqrt{\cos{y}-\cos{x}}}=2\sqrt{\frac{l}{g}}\int_{0}^{x}\frac{dy}{\sqrt{\sin^2{(x/2)}-\sin^2{(y/2)}}}$$
Now the substitution $\sin{\xi}=\sin{(y/2)}/\sin{(x/2)}$ yields to 
$$T = 4\sqrt{\frac{l}{g}}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{d\xi}{\sqrt{1-(\sin{(x/2))^2\sin^2{\xi}}}}$$
This integral does not have any primitive and must be solved numerically.

$\textbf{Adendum}$

In order to compute $dy(\xi)$ apply the chain rule to $dy(\xi)=\frac{dy}{d\xi}d\xi$. To obtain this derivative, derive the equation with the proposed change of variables with respect to $\xi$ as it follows: $$\sin{(x/2)}\cos{\xi}=\frac{1}{2}\cos{(y/2)}\frac{dy}{d\xi}=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1-\sin^2{(y/2)}}\frac{dy}{d\xi}=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1-(\sin{(x/2)}^2\sin^2{\xi}}\frac{dy}{d\xi}$$ and solve for $\frac{dy}{d\xi}$

Comment: what do you mean by no primitive and solved numerically? Like a numerical approximation method?

Comment: Yes! this integral has no closed analytic expression. You will have to apply a numerical integration rule to solve it e.g. Simpson's rule works very good even only choosing 3 integration points: $0$, $\pi/4$ and $\pi/2$

Comment: Thanks! looking at your solution made me think of the adaptive simpson's method.

Comment: @HBR: The AGM (arithmo-geometric mean) is more suited for finding values of complete elliptic integrals of the first kind, since it has quadratic convergence, see Borwein, *Pi and the AGM*.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion!!

Comment: @HBR Although this works, there are multiple ways to do this correct using different identities? Just out of curiousity

Comment: See the solution in terms of Jacobi elliptic functions [**here**](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1634148/solving-differential-equation-describing-motion-in-a-pendulum/1634177#1634177)

Comment: Yes! there are many possibilities... although this is by far the best one because it has been very deeply studied! The user Ng Chung Tak proposed another! What is more a great solution would be a Taylor expansion of the integrand in terms of the parameter $k$ if small enough.

Comment: @HBR How did you transform $dy$ to $d\xi$?

Comment: @TheStrangeQuark I made an edit

Comment: @HBR I'm still a little confused with the derivation. Where is $\sin(x/2)\cos(\xi)=\frac{1}{2}\cos(y/2)\frac{dy}{d\xi}$ coming from?

Comment: It comes from deriving the equation $\sin{\xi}=\sin{(y/2)}/\sin{(x/2)}$ (the variable change) with respect to $\xi$. The term $\sin{(x/2)}$ is constant. @TheStrangeQuark

Comment: @HBR Ok, I follow everything except where the final substitution comes from. Like where does the $\frac{dy}{\sqrt{\sin^2{(x/2)}-\sin^2{(y/2)}}}$ get substituted with $\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1-(\sin(x/2)\sin(\xi))^2}\frac{dy}{d\xi}$? I'm not seeing the equivalence to substitute there.

Comment: @TheStrangeQuark With calm, substitute my expression into the integral... you will clearly see that the two radicals cancell out and it only one of the three remains. Can you take it from this? If not write down here whatever you have tried

Comment: @HBR I am seeing that $dy = \frac{2 \sin(x/2) \cos(\xi) }{\sqrt{1-\sin^2(x/2)\sin^2(\xi)}}$ and substitution that into $T = 2 \sqrt{\frac{l}{g}}\int^x_0\frac{dy}{\sqrt{\sin^2(x/2)-\sin^2(y/2)}}$ does not cancel things out. Am I making a dumb mistake and missing something?

Comment: The fact you've missed is:
$$\cos{\xi} = \sqrt{1-\sin^2{\xi}}$$
I leave you the last step.